# Drive P channel MOSFET with Arduino, unable to get desired behaviour (LOW pin, MOSFET ON)

Tags: arduino, mosfet

After hours of building a circuit on a perfboard, I discovered that Vgs is not easy with P-MOSFETs.
After searching I figured out that I need to use either a N-MOSFET or a BJT (NPN) to bring the source voltage to the gate in order to turn the MOSFET OFF.

It is very important to me that when the Arduino pin is LOW, the MOSFET stays ON. This is to provide current to the Arduino itself if the system behind has no power left (not relevant to the circuit here).

Because of this limitation, circuits like this:
[image]

will turn off the MOSFET when arduino input is LOW. (To my understanding)
I have tried to provide the voltage to the gate using an N-MOSFET on the HIGH side, see this screenshot (apologies for not using a proper circuit software):
[image]

Despite having the N-MOSFET shown as in saturation, only 3.32V gets on it's source, not enough to trigger fully the P-MOSFET's gate.

My short knowledge of electronics has been beaten, as I cannot wrap my head around this. It would be logical to me that the N-MOSFET would apply the full drain voltage on it's source, given that the gate voltage is high.

While primary interested in a solution for this circuit here, tired of spending time on this, an explanation on to why my knowledge is flawed would be welcome.

Thanks for your time, I'll update the post if I am missing something

Comment: You wrote: "...I have tried to provide the voltage to the gate using an N-MOSFET on the HIGH side...". My answer try appoaches exactly the difficulties in order to saturate  N-channel in high side MOSFETs.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so assuming the requirements are:

- Arduino GPIO Low (0V): PMOS Switch ON (Load voltage = 12 V)
- Ardunio GPIO High (5V): PMOS Switch OFF (Load voltage = 0)

This circuit would work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyTI1o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to understand the differences between the circuit showed by Spehro and yours, is there a reason for the differences on the collector of Q1? You seem to have a voltage divider there, where Spehro has it on the base of Q2.

Comment: The location of my R5 (1k) vs his R2 (20k) makes no difference for its purpose; it is simply setting the base current for Q2 in both cases. In Sphero's the current will be ≈ (12-0.7)/20k = 0.6 mA. In my case it'll be ≈ (12-0.7)/1k = 11.1 mA. Honestly; the value I chose was arbitrary, but one advantage would be reduced unique part counts. Spehro's advantage is lower overall power consumption. Depends what you are optimizing for!

Comment: +1 They're pretty much equivalent. The main tradeoff is R4 (both circuits) that determines how fast the MOSFET turns on (too slow is hard on the MOSFET). We both picked the same number. If you want to make it switch faster, it can be reduced to (say) 1K (you could switch R5 and R4 values in Jim's circuit) 1/4-W or better.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. Since this circuit is not going to switch often (maximum once every minute), I'm not too worried about being hard on the MOSFET.

Comment: As I did not find a way to send a private message to you guys, I wanted to ask about CircuitLab you seem to use. I had a few minutes to try before my trial expired, and liked it. Despite the quite high price for a membership, do you recommand it for an hobbyist? I am currently using http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html (I will delete this comment once answered, as it is not related to the question)

Comment: I love it.. Isn't an annual membership $25 or so? Well worth it for quick simulations and sanity checks in my opinion.

Comment: This circuit may work for other purposes, but it won't let an Arduino or other MCU control its own power, since the pulldown resistor will turn it back on as soon as the MCU stops actively driving the input high in opposition to the pulldown.  For something to control it's own power, a pull resistor needs to both keep the "off" state and not bypass the power switch through the I/O protection diodes.

Comment: Agreed Chris. Was having somewhat of a tough time understanding what the "This is to provide current to the Arduino itself if the system behind has no power left" exactly meant. But I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (P-channel MOSFET capable of >12V Vgs)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVpFMO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 shifts the level to the +12, Q2 inverts the signal so the MOSFET is ON with
input LOW.

Comment: Ha. Beat me by a few mins. Well done as always Spehro

Comment: Thanks! I will try this once my will to try again has been restored, and report back.

Comment: The problem here is that the switch is on any time the input is not actively driven high.  The asker seems to want an Arduino to control its own power, and this circuit won't permit that.  While if you add a pullup resistor to keep Q1 on when the MCU is powered down, the pulling resistor may end up re-powering the MCU through the I/O protection diode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is correct. This will do what you asked for, but it is not what you need if you expect the MCU to be able to turn its own power off.

Comment: I think the OP's requirements are not totally clear. Chris may be right. Or maybe not. To the OP, if you drive Q1 low, M1 will be ON. If you drive Q1 high, then M1 will turn off, cutting power to the arduino. But once power is cut to the arduino, the input to Q1 will be low again, and M1 will turn on again. Is this what you want?

Comment: As I stated to @ChrisStratton on another comment, the 12V are not powering the Arduino. The 12 serves as a backup power source to provide current if a battery is going low. The arduino decides what "going low" means. Here, the purpose of the MOSFET is to remove the backup supply when the Arduino decides itself and the other devices can run on the battery alone. (When the backup power is ON, the 12V will power the devices, when the MOSFET turns OFF, only the battery voltage will be here.

Comment: This way, there are three states possible. The 25V from the battery main supply/solar controller is present, and high enough to qualify as "high enough", and the arduino turns the MOSFET off, by driving the pin HIGH. This leads to the 12V not entering the system. Another state is the 25V being present, but at actually 23V, which the Arduino considers low, so it will bring the backup power to drive the 12V rail of the circuit (there is a DC-DC between the 25V and 12V rail). The arduino being on the 25V rail, does not get power from the 12V rail.

Comment: The last state, and the one why I have my requirements of pin low = MOSFET ON, is when the 25V rail is totally empty (battery missing + solar controller not providing any electricity). The 12V rail will then be active, with the MOSFET on. This will allow the current to go from the OUT pins of the DC-DC (for 25->12V), to the IN pins, providing 12V to the 25V rail, going through the body diode of the DC-DC buck (not optimal but better than nothing). This way, the Arduino will get power, and be able to assess the situation and keep the gate low.

Comment: The devices on the 12V rail are to never, ever be turned off. They, with my setup, get powered from different sources, depending on what is available. Unless the battery fails/missing, no solar current, and the house lost electricity (the 12V supply in this circuit is a power brick giving 12VDC), it won't turn off. The 25V rail is connected to the battery, and can be supplied with only 12V for any number of time. The only devices that rely on this rail are the DC-DC 25v->12v, some human switched lights and smartphone charger

Comment: What about using two NPN transistors instead of NPN and PNP?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is not suitable for drive N-channel in high side position.
Use a P-channel mosfet or provide a \$Vg\$ higher than \$Vd + Vgs_{TH}\$ (ex. using bootstrap techniques).    Some examples (below), showing how to drive high side switches according you require - pin low -> load on.

[image: High side drives]

Comment: "This is to provide current to the Arduino itself if the system behind has no power left (not relevant to the circuit here)." Actually, if that is your goal, it is **extremely** critically relevant, as an MCU that is going to control its own power must use a non-inverting switch made of two semiconductors.  If you try to use a normal single FET inverting switch, you'll end up turning yourself back on through the I/O protection diodes and keeper resistor.

Comment: @Chris Startton: I confess that I did not understand anything of what you wrote.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The 12V are not going directly into the Arduino. The arduino has a separate DC-DC buck converting 25V into the 5V, from another separate source. The 12V here is backup power if the 25V is missing. But I'm curious on how you can turn the Arduino back on from the output pin, could that happen with Spehro or Jim's examples?

Comment: @Cubox - it doesn't matter that it is not going directly.  Your desire to control a high-side switch such that it is on when an I/O pin is low is basically incompatible with self power control, for any MCU that has protection diodes clamping the I/Os to the power rails.